# How to configure multiple Quartz single-threaded jobs

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have 2 different jobs, what must be triggered in the same time.

I'd like to give a separate thread for every of them. 
Of course i can configure Quartz to use only one thread, setting property

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
```

But it means, that both jobs will be using the same thread. If I set threadCount = 2, it is possible that the first job will be triggered twice, and the other job will wait.

So, how could I run these jobs in separate threads independently?

My Spring configuration is like that:

```
<bean name="Job1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  <property name="jobClass" value="test.job1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="CronTrigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="Job1"/>
  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 * 6-21 * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean name="Job2" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  <property name="jobClass" value="test.job2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="CronTrigger2" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="Job2"/>
  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 * 6-21 * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
  <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown">
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property name="configLocation">
    <value>classpath:quartz.properties</value>
  </property>
  <property name="triggers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="CronTrigger1"/>
      <ref bean="CronTrigger2"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Why do you think the first job will be scheduled twice because of the bigger threadvpool?

Comment: If i schedule job execution every minute, and the last execution took more than a minute, then scheduler can execute the second instance of the job in a parallel... Am i right?

Comment: I am thinking you may need two different SchedulerFactoryBeans. Why do you need this btw? Are you classes not thread safe?

Comment: @chrislovecnm The jobs call 3rd party web services. They are slow, and parallel execution of the same web service creates performance problems. But thanks a lot, it seems that different SchedulerFactoryBeans will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is that you use different SchedulerFactoryBeans.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that annotate your job class with @DisallowConcurrentExecution. See [the Quartz documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html).